# UART1_Write(13); is not running

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, mikroc

I'm using a PIC16F688 to read from analog channel 2 and average the values of the pressure sensor and then convert the 4 bytes to digital using ASCII character method.

I don't need any kind of delay after sending the results to UART1_Write(temp[i]).

My problem is that the UART 13 is not working properly as carriage return. 
The output from terminal looks like this: 000000000
                                             0000
                                             0000
                                             000000000
when tt should be sending pure 0000 every time (and depending on my pressure on the sensor, from 0000 to 1023).

```
   char *temp = "0000";
   unsigned int adc_value;
   int i;
   int average = 0;

   void main() 
   {
     OSCCON = 0x77;  //8MHz
     ANSEL = 0b00000100;  //ANS2
     CMCON0 = 0X07;  
     TRISA = 0b00001100;
     UART1_Init(9600);
     Delay_ms(100);

     while (1)  //infinte loop
     { 
       average=0;
       for(i=0;i<10;i++){
         average+= ADC_Read(2);
       }
       average/=10;
       temp[0] = average/1000+48;
       temp[1] = (average/100)%10+48;
       temp[2] = (average/10)%10+48;
       temp[3] = average%10+48;
       for (i=0;i<4; i++){
         UART1_Write(temp[i]);
       }
       UART1_Write(13); // back slash
       //delay_ms(10);
     }
   }
```

Comment: `char *temp = "0000";` points to a *string literal* so you must not try to write to it with `temp[0] = average/1000+48;` etc. Better to declare it as `char temp[] = "0000";`

Answer (score 0):

you are writing a line feed, or `\r` where you'd probably want to send either `\r\n` or only `\n` depending on your terminal. I'd recomend some tool to read your terminal in hex. In linux `cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | hexdump` would work.

Ps. using + '0' makes your character conversion somewhat more legible, but i think xc8 comes with stdlib.h so you can use `itoa()`.

Good luck